# How to open REPL in vim using fireplace plugin

Tags: vim, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have `vim-fireplace` plugin installed using https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace's readme as follows:

1. First `cider-nrepl` installation by adding line `{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.28.5"]]}}` to `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file.
2. Then copy-pasted installation instructions for fireplace from README.
3. Then installed `salve.vim` by following its readme from the provided link.

Now I want to use fireplace by opening two separate windows in vim, one for the clojure code file and another for the REPL. I started repl in terminal using `lein repl` and then in vim `:Connect nrepl://127.0.0.1:60356` gives `not an editor command` error. Also Note: I tried `:Eval` to evaluate a code but vim says **not an editor command**. Can you tell me where is the mistake in the installation or execution of vim-fireplace plugin?

Also link to vim-fireplace commands/keys guide will be helpful.

Comment: Fireplace commands may only work, if you are in a `*.clj*` file (out of my head I am not sure, if this is a fireplace thing). So if commands like `:Connect` are not there even on your `project.clj` file, then your installation of the fireplace plugin did not work. If you are using Salve, you can also use `:Console`, which then will give you a separate REPL (:term, xorg term, tmux, ...)

Comment: The plugin comes with documentation. Use it: `:help fireplace`.

Answer (score 1):

Fireplace commands only work, if you are in a `*.clj*` file.

So if commands like `:Connect` are not there even when in your `project.clj` file, then your installation of the fireplace plugin did not work.

If you are using Salve, you can also use `:Console`, which then will give you a separate REPL (:term, xorg term, tmux, ...)

Comment: How to open the REPL screen in vim vertically where I can use it like regular REPL inside vim (like Emacs you have REPL screen)? It is like having two split screens, left side the ```clj``` file is opened and on the right side, the REPL is working (just like what we see REPL on terminal window) where I can try some clojure forms independently of the code on left hand side.